# css loaded as image/png

Tags: javascript, css, tabbed

This question is probably not the best SO practice but I really don't have a clue of what is going on in here.

One of my .css files sometimes (~50% of the times) is loaded as an image. Here the screenshot:

[image]

which is supposed to be `text/css` (as it's loaded the other ~50% of the times).

The other interesting part is that this happens **only** in the pages loading also the two following files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tabcontent.js" ></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tab-content/template5/tabcontent.css"/>
```

as described in **[here](http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content)**. I tried removing the `javaScript` only and my `css` loads just fine. Have you ever had this issue?

Comment: Is there a chance the js has an error? Or malformed function?  If you place the js call AFTER the css load, does it ever error then?  Additionally put a second load call after the js to show/prove that the js is the issue.

Comment: is the CSS not working when it is loaded this way?

Comment: I know that styles should actually be loaded first, try _all_ the stylesheets above the scripts, does it make a difference?

Comment: Also is that referenced path the correct one?  If not, it's a clue to where the issue is in the js.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions Hi thanks for your comment. Paths are fine, there are other pages (in the same folder) loading the same .css using that path. I place the js call **after** as you said and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @epoch Thanks for that I did and I works very well now.

Answer (score 1):

image/png is the MIME type. I'm not sure how Javascript would overrite this, but you could try adding the following code to your .htaccess file

```
AddType text/css .css
```

this tells your server to send the content type in the header.